# What is "dont" and "isnt" in the pertained GloVe vector files (e.g. glove.6B.50d.txt)?

Tags: neural-network, nlp, word-embedding, glove

I found these 2 words "dont" and "isnt" in the vector file glove.6B.50d.txt downloaded from https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/. I wonder if they were originally "don't" and "isn't". This will likely depend on the sentence_to_word parsing algorithms they used. If someone is familiar, please confirm if this is the case.

A secondary question is if this is a common way to deal with apostrophe for words like "don't", "isn't", "hasn't" and so on. i.e. just filter replace that apostrophe with an empty string such that "don" and "t" becomes one word.

Finally, I am also not sure if GloVe comes with API to do sentence_to_word parsing so you can be consistent with what the researchers have done originally.

Answer (score 0):

I think dont and isnt really are originally don't and isn't. I have seen a few other such examples. I suspect this is just the specific way GloVe researchers handle this.